# In a <meta>, what is the correct Dublin Core property name to express distinctly spatial and temporal coverage?

Tags: meta, rdfa, dublin-core

I have an application where some `<meta>` must be included to the pages for RDFa.
I had to merely report the properties stated by my client in its requirement document.
All was fine for many properties like `dc:title`, `dc:subject`, etc.

But two requirements appeared more complicated for me. They were precisely expressed like this:

- `dc:coverage (spatial)`
- `dc:coverage (temporal)`

Being not a guru about RDFa, I looked for more information and found that in the real HTML `<meta>`it could be expressed like this:

- `dc:coverage.spatial`
- `dc:coverage.temporal`

But now a third party representing the crawler that will use my page says me that those properties don't exist!

So I can't figure out what I should actually write in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dublin Core defined two sub-properties for the [`coverage`](http://purl.org/dc/terms/coverage) property: [`spatial`](http://purl.org/dc/terms/spatial) and [`temporal`](http://purl.org/dc/terms/temporal). This parent-child relationship is specified in the RDF definition; there is no need to refer to the super-property when using its sub-property.

If it’s a spatial value:

```html
<meta property="dc:spatial" content="" />
```

If it’s a temporal value:

```html
<meta property="dc:temporal" content="" />
```

If it’s unknown whether it’s a spatial or temporal value:

```html
<meta property="dc:coverage" content="" />
```

Comment: Wow! So simple... Thanks a lot.